# interpret an awk command in bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to interpret an awk command in a script. The command contains a variable that contains the normal number of fields in a file and I want to get rid of the line that do not match this number of fields.

Here is my code:

```
filename='myfile.txt'

nbfields=$(head -1 $filename | awk -F '|' '{print NF}')
awkcommand="awk -F '|' 'NF=="$nbfields"{print \$0}'"

$awkcommand > 'myotherfile.txt'
```

When executing, I get the error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: 'NF==3{print
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

I tried with and without the `\` before `$0`, but it's the same.

I could make it work by using eval, but I'd like to avoid using eval if possible. As I understand it, it's dangerous to use it. Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `head`, you can do:

```
nbfields=$(awk -F '|' '{print NF;exit}' file)
```

Better to use a function to store awk command:

```
awkcommand() { awk -F '|' -v n=$nbfields 'NF==n' file; }
```

Also note correct way of passing a shell variable to awk using `-v` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasn't aware of the -v option. Neat. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to count number of fields based on first row and then print all the rows in the file that have the same number of fields. Correct?

You can do that like this -

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{i=0}{if(i==0){fields=NF;i=1} if (fields==NF) print $0;}'
```

Comment: Yes, that works. But actually, I'm getting the number of fields from a different file. That's why I need to pass a variable to awk.